# Como tirar repetição de query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Eu criei um chat, e tenho uma query pra exibir as outras contas do site para iniciar uma conversa. Coloquei um select all, e exibe todos normalmente, mas agora preciso colocar um order by pra ordenar eles de acordo com as mensagens mais recentes, então tive de colocar um inner join com a tabela de mensagens.

Meu select está assim:

```
SELECT contas.Key_User, contas.Login_User, contas.User_Image, chat.Key_User1, chat.Key_User2, chat.Date 
FROM contas 
INNER JOIN chat 
ON contas.Key_User = chat.Key_User1 OR contas.Key_User = chat.Key_User2 OR contas.Key_User > 0 
WHERE `Key_User` not like '".$_SESSION['Key_User']."'
ORDER BY chat.Date DESC
```

O where é pra não aparecer a própria conta do usuário. No entanto, com o inner join, agora ele repete as contas para cada mensagem que existe dele, então se o usuário tem dez mensagens ao todo, vai aparecer o perfil dez vezes, e queria limitar pra aparecer uma vez só, ou outra forma de dar um order by pela data da mensagem.

Já tentei usar distinct, mas não consegui encaixar o group by.

```
chat.Key_User1: Key_User do usuário logado
chat.Key_User2: Key_User do usuário que vai receber a mensagem.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar funções de agregação com `GROUP BY` para agrupar linhas com os mesmos campos e limitar pela data mais recente utilizando `MAX`.

```
SELECT
    contas.Key_User,
    contas.Login_User,
    contas.User_Image,
    chat.Key_User1,
    chat.Key_User2,
    MAX(chat.Date) -- Esta linha limita os resultados a data mais recente
FROM contas

INNER JOIN chat ON (
    contas.Key_User = chat.Key_User1
    OR contas.Key_User = chat.Key_User2
    OR contas.Key_User > 0
)

WHERE `Key_User` not like '".$_SESSION['Key_User']."'

GROUP BY contas.Key_User,
    contas.Login_User,
    contas.User_Image,
    chat.Key_User1,
    chat.Key_User2

ORDER BY chat.Date DESC
```

Como o campo `chat.Key_User2` não está em nenhuma função de agregação haverão linhas com usuários repetidos porém com destinatários diferentes, caso queira que haja apenas uma linha por usuário utilize uma função de agregação nele ou remova o campo `chat.Key_User2`.

Link sobre funções de agregação: https://www.devmedia.com.br/sql-funcoes-de-agregacao/38463

Comment: Funcionou! Na verdade, ainda estava repetindo, mas só duas vezes agora, e eu consegui resolver tirando o chat.Key_User1 e chat.Key_User2 do GROUP BY. E eu removi o chat.Key_User2 do SELECT também, como você sugeriu, e ficou perfeito.

Comment: Mas por algum motivo, o ORDER BY não está funcionando. Sempre que eu dou F5, ele muda a ordem dos usuários, mas não devia acontecer isso porque não tem novas mensagens. Você sabe o que poderia ser?

Comment: Pode ocorrer de dois usuários terem uma conversa no mesmo momento, como a ordenação está apenas pelo `chat.Date` ele utiliza um critério interno para ordenar dados com a mesma data, uma opção é adicionar um critério secundário no `GROUP BY` deste modo:
`ORDER BY chat.Date DESC, contas.Key_User`